# Android Studio - nonexistent device visible as Connected

Tags: android-studio, adb, android-studio-3.0

When I want to Run an app in my Android Studio, there is some weird phone (Motorola XT1052) shown as "connected". And I can even run an app on that device. However, I don't have and never had such phone. I don't have any phones connected via USB, and this Motorola is visible all the time, even after restarting the computer.

I used to have "ADB WIFI" plugin and I thought that it might be the cause, however, after uninstalling it, the device is still visible. How can I delete this device?

I'm having problems with emulator in general, I can't run any app as it always hangs on "waiting for target device to come online", so I wonder if that weird ghost phone might be the problem, since no other solution helped me with the emulator.

[image: imaginary phone connected]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I finally got is so I figured I'd share what I've found out.

Look for some other emulators that might be running. In my case, it was a program called Bluestacks. Turns out you can actually install your own apps on it through Android Studio.